# Monitor fails randomly

Tags: blank-screen, defective-hardware

I have an HP Pavillion 27xi LED IPS monitor that randomly fails and fails in different ways. In this I mean that some times it works for 30 seconds then goes black with the power light still on. Other times, the screen comes on but then the OSD menu freezes on the screen. Sometimes it doesnt even get that far and it just stays black but the power light comes on. Also, in the rare occurance that it turns on and stays on, if the resolution is changed or signal is lost for a split second, it goes black.

I would also like to mention that by black I mean black. It is not the backlight going out that is a problem. Also, I am running multiple mobitors and the other two work fine throughout these failures so that should rule out the video card (which is brand new).

I have tried different cables (2 different HDMI cables and a DVI instead) and there is no difinitive difference. I have also tried changing out the power supply with a different one.

My question then is, what hardware component could be the issue to cause these inconsistant failures? I would think that if something was truly bad it would produce consistant failures but it is not.

Comment: I'd suspect capacitors. I've seen similar stuff happen with an old, capasitor plague era monitor

Comment: I just opened it up again and double checked the capacitors on the video board. I tested them with multi-meter and they seem to be working fine from what I can tell. Sorry for my lack of knowledge. I'm trying to learn and fix my monitor at the same time.

Comment: Nix that last comment, I think I found a leaky cap. Going to try to replace it and see if that fixes it

Comment: http://darkerview.com/darkview/index.php?/archives/876-LCD-Monitor-Repair.html and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24246/what-other-than-capacitor-rot-could-cause-a-capacitor-to-bulge-and-fail are worth reading

Comment: I'd also add the last time I replaced capasitors on a monitor, the next cap, and the one after that and... so on failed. Eventually the backlight went borked as well and I gave up. Might need to be mentally prepared for other cap failures.

Comment: I am facing this exact problem on 27xi now.  Did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: Nope, I ended up selling it for parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the 'modern' LED backlit monitor dosen't have an inverter, and there's no CCFL bulbs to fail, chances are its a capacitor. Monitor capacitors tend to be 1) abused badly 2) cheap.

If you're going to replace them, don't forget to get a quality capasitor with low ESR for long life, rather than any random cheap one.

Comment: Okay so I need to replace a 220uF 16V smd cap. In addition to the farad and volt ratings, there is a specification of "J25". What does that indicate? Do I need to get a identical capacitor for this to work correctly?

Comment: So I have been fiddling around with this for probably a couple weeks now and I have come to the conclusion that there is a bad mini capacitor somewhere that I cannot find. I tried to remove one and failed at getting it back on (also removed the pad) and I have come to the conclusion that I should refrain from trying to mess with them. However, put it back together and powered it up and I am typing on that monitor right now. I remove a piece and it works better, go figure. I'll probably stick to the bigger can capacitors in the future.

Comment: Anything that's not a regular electrolytic is probably going to need more work/skills than the average hobbyist can do. Not even sure how you'd work out a surface mount cap is faulty